# Are read_volatile and write_volatile atomic for usize?

Tags: rust

I want to use `read_volatile` and `write_volatile` for IPC using shared memory. Is it guaranteed that writing of an unsigned integer of `usize` type will be atomic?

Comment: Uff. Tough question. Although this entire thing makes me wonder if there are better solutions for your problem that don't require this kind of low level knowledge; like pipes. But of course I don't know your situation, so I really can only wonder.

Comment: @Finomnis my biggest motivation is that I care about latencies on a sub microsecond level.

Comment: From the docs for your functions: "Just like in C, whether an operation is volatile has no bearing whatsoever on questions involving concurrent access from multiple threads. Volatile accesses *behave exactly like non-atomic accesses* in that regard. In particular, a race between a read_volatile and any write operation to the same location is undefined behavior.". Did you consider using `AtomicUsize`?

Comment: @rodrigo I have a big block of memory shared between processes (not threads). Would AtomicUsize be of any help there?

Comment: @rodrigo also, one would expect that read or write of 64bit number from/to RAM would be an atomic operation on 64bit cpu, so I would assume that unless write_volatile goes out of its way to translate this into multiple writes, this should be atomic.

Comment: I mean, it has the same memory layout than an `usize` but with atomic guarantees. I guessed that is what you need. And yes, that is a reasonably expectation, and that even _may_ be true in your system, but the documentation is clear: read_volatile and any write operation may race and cause undefined behaivor.

Comment: Moreover, if in your arch, a regular read cannot cause a race, then reading an `AtomicUsize` will have no additional runtime penalty. That is, any additional performance loss of using atomics will be caused because they are actually required.

Comment: @SamuelHapak To my knowledge, there are three facets to lock-free atomics: 1) being able to write/read it atomically; 2) volatile, meaning preventing the compiler from optimizing away the read/write, and 3) instruction ordering / memory fences (compiler is free to reorder instructions in whatever way it sees fit, as long as he thinks the outcome in a single-threaded system will be the same). To my understanding 1) and 2) is given (64 bit write should be a single cycle on 64 bit systems; and volatile is obvious as this is what your functions do).

Comment: I don't know about 3); but I'd almost assume that it will work. But no guarantees, this is just from my understanding.

Comment: But I agree with @rodrigo; AtomicUsize is binary compatible with Usize and gives you all 3 points for free. Just check in a disassembly if it behaves as you expect, but I'd argue it will, always.

Comment: @Finomnis: I think that many archs require explicit memory barriers to guarantee atomicity for values of any size. It is not only that reading/writing is a single cycle, there is also multiple layers of cache that may or may not be shared between cores, and probably other details that I don't even know the name of. Lock-free primitives are hard...

Comment: @rodrigo To my knowledge, in x86 at least (I don't know about other architectures) it's the CPU's responsibility to synchronize caches between cores, and volatile is usually write-through. But again I didn't deal with those things for a while, so I might be incorrect. Memory barriers are just to prevent the compiler from rearranging the writes/reads.

Comment: @Finomnis: But x86 CPUs have instructions such as `mfence`, `lfence` and others. Note that modern CPUs may rearrange accesses to memory even when the compiler did not (out-of-order execution I think it is called).

Comment: Thank you. So, it can in theory happen that only half of my 64bit integer gets written into memory, unless I use Atomic, right? And the code should look like

unsafe {ptr::write_volatile(ptr, AtomicUsize::new(num));};

?

Comment: It is not that only half will be written, but that if you write concurrently or write and read concurrently you get _undefined behavior_, not just have read data. Trying to analyze how much undefined is a _fool's errand_.

Comment: @rodrigo thanks, so would the example code I wrote above (atomic + write_volatile combination) there work actually? And, what other kinds of undefined behaviour besides reading only half of the integer can actually happen?

Comment: @SamuelHapak If you invoke UB you could get a [daemon out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)! Anyway, if you use atomics I think you do not need volatile access any more, that you get for free.

Comment: @rodrigo and Finomnis, thanks guys for all the help. If any of you want to transform the discussion into the answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @SamuelHapak: I've been out for a few days, but I'll take it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, Rust does not have a proper memory model, but instead it uses that imposed by the LLVM, that is basically that of C++, that in turn is inherited fom C. So the best references you have of what is guaranteed doing memory stuff is that from C.

In C `volatile` should not be used for syncronization, its intended use is for memory mapped I/O and maybe for single-threaded signal handlers. See for example this [Linux-kernel specific gideline](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/volatile-considered-harmful.html). Or this other [description of volatile](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv):

> This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, **but not with another thread of execution**.

If you want to do concurrent access to a value you should use atomics operations. <s>They have the volatile guarantee plus additional ones.</s> They are guaranteed to be atomic even in the presence of concurrent access. And moreover they allow you to set the ordering mode.

For your particular case you should use [`AtomicUsize`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/index.html). Note that the availability of that type is conditioned on your architecture having the necessary support, but that is exactly what you want.

Note that an `AtomicUsize` has the same memory layout of a plain `usize`, so if you have a `usize` embedded in a shared struct you can access atomically with a pointer cast. I think this code is sound:

```
struct SharedData {
    // ...
    x: usize
}

fn test(data: *mut SharedData) {
    let x = unsafe { &*(&(*data).x as *const usize as *const AtomicUsize) };
    let _ = x.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
}
```

Although you would be better just declaring that `x` as `AtomicUsize` directly.

Also note that reading or writing that value using any non-atomic operation (even just reading it out of curiosity, even using volatile access) invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://predr.ag/blog/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-undefined-behavior/).

Comment: Are you sure about the volatile guarantees? It seems from what I read that compiler is allowed to drop some atomic writes and reads, unlike volatile.

Comment: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4455.html#n4455-no-sane-compiler-would-optimize-atomics

Comment: @SamuelHapak TBH, I have no idea. The linked paper says _Atomic operations are unsuitable to express that memory locations can be externally modified_ and then suggests using `volatile atomic` for those cases, but that is not available in Rust, AFAIK. Anyway, I think that a proper use of atomics should compatible with the allowed optimizations, for the purposes of thread or process synchronization. If not, what is the point of atomics in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, my reading of the paper is: atomics are fine as long as you care about reading and storing the values. However, if your store or read is supposed to have a side effect (eg making sound for every single store), you need to use volatile

Comment: @SamuelHapak: That is my (new) understanding, yes: you either use volatile to access memory mapped hardware or use atomics to do shared-access synchronization. If for some weird reason you need both you are out of luck for now, as is the author of this [rust-internals thread](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/atomic-cmpxchg-with-volatile-semantics/4101).